# Chartjs Horizontal Bar, the width of the Bars does not change

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have implemented a Horizontal Bar chart using Chartjs, Im required to display the bars along with legends.
However, in the very process of doing so, I am not able to alter the width of the bars.
If I go to add the dataset to a single array object, then I don't get the legends with different colors.
In order to achieve the legends for each item on my y axis (Horizontal bar chart) , I have included dataset to be

```
 data: [99, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
```

as above,

```js
var chrt = document.getElementById("chartId").getContext("2d");

var chartId = new Chart(chrt, {
   type: 'Capacity',
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
      datasets: [
         {
            label: "Amkor-FJ",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            data: [99, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            borderColor: 'yellow',
            borderWidth: 1,

         },
         {
            label: "ASE-CL",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            data: [null, 97, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            borderColor: 'yellow',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
         {
            label: "ASE-KH",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            data: [null, null, 100, null, null, null, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "red",
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },

         {
            label: "ATMC",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            // data: [99, 97, 100, 110, 105, 87, 85, 100, 92],
            data: [null, null, null, 110, null, null, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "red",
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
         {
            label: "Global7",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            // data: [99, 97, 100, 110, 105, 87, 85, 100, 92],
            data: [null, null, null, null, 105, null, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "red",
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
         {
            label: "SSMC",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            // data: [99, 97, 100, 110, 105, 87, 85, 100, 92],
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 87, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "green",
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
         {
            label: "TSMC8",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            // data: [99, 97, 100, 110, 105, 87, 85, 100, 92],
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, 85, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "green",
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
         {
            label: "TSTSTAT",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            // data: [92, 100, 85, 87, 105, 110, 100, 97, 99],
            // data: [99, 97, 100, 110, 105, 87, 85, 100, 92],
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 100, null],
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            borderColor: 'yellow',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
         {
            label: "UMCF8E",
            // labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 92],
            // data: [99, 97, 100, 110, 105, 87, 85, 100, 92],
            backgroundColor: "green",
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
         },
      ],

   },
   options: {
      indexAxis: 'y',
      elements: {
         bar: {
            borderWidth: 2,
         }
      },
      plugins: {
         legend: {
            display: true,

            position: "bottom",
            align: "left"
         }
      },
      legend: {
         labels: {
            boxWidth: 1
         }
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
  categorySpacing: 0,
  barThickness : 73
}],
         x: {
            beginAtZero: true,

            ticks: {                  
               callback: function (value) {
                  return (value / 100 * 100).toFixed(0) + '%'; // convert it to percentage
               },
            },
            scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
               labelString: 'Percentage',
            },
         }
      }
   }

});
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; width:400px; height:400px">
  <canvas id="chartId" aria-label="chart" width="350px"
     height="300px"></canvas>
</div>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.1.1/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: removed chart.js script of version2.9.4. 
but there's no change

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the data for each dataset using data property but in fact you have set some of the values to null, this might cause some problem. Try to modify your code like so using barThickness for each dataset :

```
var chrt = document.getElementById("chartId").getContext("2d");

var chartId = new Chart(chrt, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ["Amkor-FJ", "ASE-CL", "ASE-KH", "ATMC", "Global7", "SSMC", "TSMC8", "TSTSTAT", "UMCF8E"],
      datasets: [
         {
            label: "Amkor-FJ",
            data: [99, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            borderColor: 'yellow',
            borderWidth: 1,
            barThickness: 20 // Set the width of the bars for this dataset
         },
         // Add other datasets here with their respective barThickness values
      ]
   },
   options: {
      // Add any other options as needed
   }
});
```

By the way, If you'd like to include legends for each items on the y axis, you can add a legend configuration like so :

```
var chartId = new Chart(chrt, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      // Data and datasets here
   },
   options: {
      legend: {
         display: true,
         position: 'right', // Position of the legend
         labels: {
            boxWidth: 10, // Width of the legend color box
            padding: 10 // Padding between legend items
         }
      }
   }
});
```